# slim import error with spyder: 'path' must be None or a list, not <class '_frozen_importlib_external._NamespacePath'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, spyder

When I import slim with spyder:

```
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim
```

there is an error:

> ```
> RuntimeError: 'path' must be None or a list, not <class'_frozen_importlib_external._NamespacePath'>
> ```

[image]

And the jupyter notebook is ok.

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a bug in Spyder that we'll fix in our **3.2.7** version, to be released on March 2018.

Please take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/5299) for a temporary fix.